# Can you separate independent clauses after the word 'because'?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, syntactic-analysis

I get confused when the following happens:

> Graham was angry because Lee burned the toast and Jennifer finished
>   the milk.

Should there be a comma between 'toast' and 'Jennifer'?

The statement *Lee burned the toast* and the statement *Jennifer finished the milk* seem like they could function as standalone sentences. From what I have read, anything that functions as a standalone sentence is known as an 'independent clause',  and when you separate two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction such as 'and', you need to insert a comma.

However, Graham is angry because both of these things ruined his breakfast, but adding a comma would seem, to me, set off a separate statement which is unrelated to his anger.

> Graham was angry because Lee burned the toast
>
> And Jennifer finished the milk

Is the comma always included, never included, or sometimes included (depending on the idea being communicated)?

Thank you so much for reading this!

Comment: No need for a comma. _Lee burned the toast_ and _Jennifer finished the milk_ could stand alone  as independent clauses, but here they dependents of the preposition "because". More specifically, they are a coordination of declarative clauses functioning as complements of the preposition "because", i.e. they are part of the PP _because [Lee burned the toast] and [Jennifer finished the milk]_.

Comment: Thank you, Bill. Does PP stand for prepositional phrase?

Comment: Yes, PP stands for 'preposition phrase'.